# How to concatenate columns of two tables in One table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I concatenate table1 selected columns and table2 selected columns and both the result in one table in two different columns?

table1 concatenated columns in coulmn_A and table2 concatenated columns in table_B

here is my tables:

table1 (name,age,salary,id) and table2(address,city,id)

where id column in table2 is a foreign key of table1.

Comment: please provide some sample data @Jason

Comment: what kind of sample data? I have provided the table columns names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your problem statement correctly then the below code might work for you -

```
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE(coulmn_A,coulmn_B)
SELECT NAME + CAST(AGE AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST(SALARY AS VARCHAR(100)) + CAST(T1.ID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [coulmn_A],
       CAST(ADDRESS AS VARCHAR(2000)) + CITY + CAST(T2.ID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [coulmn_B]
FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Assumption - `ID` column working as a relationship between your `table1` and `table2.`

Also casting the columns from both the tables to `VARCHAR` to avoid any datatype conversion issues (the real structure of your tables would have helped in correct datatype and size usage).

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code.

```
Insert INTO TargetTable
(
ColumnA,
ColumnB
)
Select Cast(T1.name AS Nvarchar(max)) + Cast(T1.age AS Nvarchar(max))+Cast(T1.salary AS Nvarchar(max))+ Cast(T1.id AS Nvarchar(max)) AS coulmn_A  ,Cast(T2.address AS Nvarchar(max))+Cast(T2.city AS Nvarchar(max))+Cast(T2.id AS Nvarchar(max)) As coulmn_B From Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table T2 
ON T1.ID=T2.ID
```

Assumption: ID Column is used as foreign key in table 2

NOTE: Try to cast columns with same data types in order to concatenate multiple columns

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For your valuable posts. I have done using below code:

```
SELECT p.name+','+cast(p.salary as varchar(50))+','+cast(p.age as varchar(50)) as column_A, d.city+', '+cast(d.id as varchar(10)) AS column_B from test2 as p inner join test as d on d.id=p.testid+122
```